# Google Map fetch dynamic LatLng index

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, json

My code below trigger a simple Google Map event when the user click on the marker:

```
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'click', function() {
    console.log(this.position);
 }
```

It displays the current position of the clicked marker like this:

```
 of {j: 51.469722, C: -0.4513890000000629}
```

In my application, I was fetching the Latitude and the Longitude of the clicked marker by using the index of the returned position:

```
 var positions = this.position;
 var latitude  = positions[0].j;
 var longitude = positions[0].C;
```

It was working fine until i found out that the index of this.position are dynamic, it can change at any time. instead of j and C I can have k and D as an index for each element of the position object.

Can someone help me to figure it out how I can manipulate the position of a marker without hard-coding the index and not breaking my code if the letters change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lat = this.getPosition().lat();
var lng = this.getPosition().lng();
```

Generally there are getters and setters for many things in GM, and you should look for those in the docs before going into the inspector.

Comment: You're right, I'm ashamed how the answer to this problem was so simple. thank you!

Comment: I went through the same thing learning google maps myself. Cheers.